# Almost everywhere equal plurisubharminic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I just have a simple question that if two plurisubharminic functions take the same values almost everywhere, can one conclude that they are the same function? If not, could anyone provide  a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is mentioned in the book *Methods of the Theory of Functions of Many Complex Variables* by V.S. Vladimirov at the end of section $9.8$.

A short way to prove it is to use the fact that for a function $u$ with a well-defined Hessian in the sense of distributions, such that the said Hessian is positive semi-definite, there is a **unique** pluri-subharmonic function that coincides with $u$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out a much elementary proof using only the definition of psh functions and the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. Thank you for answering though!

Comment: @Che-HungHuang You're welcome!